# Botão ficando escondido

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tenho 2 váriaveis quando elas deixam de ser nulas são criados dois botões, o problema é que um sempre aparece escondido, se eu inspecionar o código ele ta lá, porém na tela não aparece nada, estou desconfiando que é por causa que os dois estão tentando ser criados no mesmo lugar, e um está bugando o outro.

código de criação do botão com erro:

```
if (isset($_POST['escondido']))
{
  print "<button type='button' href='' target='' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalImagens'><strong>Imagens do componente</strong></button>";
}
```

Comment: Se possível coloca o `html` e o`css` aplicado aos botões...

Comment: é aquele ali que eu postei, o html gerado é exatamente aquele ali.

Comment: Certo, mas esses botões não estão em nenhuma, `div` ? não há nenhum `css` sendo atribuído a eles?

Comment: Nenhuma div, somente o css padrão do bootsstrap.

Comment: ok, se possível coloca o `html` que está sendo gerado pelo php...

Comment: No inspecionar elemento do browser não tem nenhum regra que está ocultando esses botões no css?

Comment: O código aí da pergunta só tem um botão mesmo, que só aparece quando a variável "escondido" é enviada por POST. 
Você não está confundindo que tem dois por causa da tag de fechamento não?

Comment: A propósito, tag button não precisa de type='button'.

Comment: Kenny nenhuma regra

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta Antonio

Comment: Pra testar se realmente está sendo criado na mesma posição na tela, experimente inserir um `<br>` após o fechamento do botão.

Comment: você está misturando php e javascript sem distinguir eles é isso?

Comment: Não, estou separando php e javascript, cada um em sua tag normal.

Comment: Lucas, fiz oque você pediu porém como aquele botão não é mostrado o br também não.

Comment: `Button` não tem `href` nem `target`, só pra avisar.